# Why am I getting null pointer in the getGraphObject when trying to post a image to facebook from android?

Tags: android, multithreading, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to post a photo from an url to the facebook. So, I have a method that converts the image located in the provided url to a bitmap, after that I want to publish the image to the facebook photos of the user. This is my code:

Method that converts image located in a URL to a Bitmap image:

```
public Bitmap downloadImage(String url) {
   Bitmap bm = null;
   try {
       URL aURL = new URL(url);
       URLConnection conn = aURL.openConnection();
       conn.connect();
       InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
       BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
       bm = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
       bis.close();
       is.close();
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e("Hub","Error getting the image from server : " + e.getMessage().toString());
   } 
   return bm;
}
```

This is where I try to post the image in the facebook:

```
private void postToFacebook(byte[] data) {
   Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

   if (session != null) {

       Bundle postParams = new Bundle();
       postParams.putString("caption", "Teste caption");
       postParams.putByteArray("picture", data);

       Request.Callback callback = new Request.Callback() {
           public void onCompleted(Response response) {
               JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
               String postId = null;
               try {
                   postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
               } catch (JSONException e) {
                   Log.i("", "JSON error "+ e.getMessage());
               }
               FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
               if (error != null) {
                   Toast.makeText(getContext(), error.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   } else {
                       Toast.makeText(getContext(), postId, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
               }
           }
       };

           Request request = new Request(session, "me/photos", postParams, HttpMethod.POST, callback);

       RequestAsyncTask task = new RequestAsyncTask(request);
       task.execute();
   } else {
    Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Not logged", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
   }
```

But at this line: response.getGraphObject(), I am getting the null pointer exception. I've tried to execute in a background thread, like this:

```
class ConvertImageTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, byte[]> {
AsyncTask<Params,Progress,Result>
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute(); // do nothing here
}

@Override
protected byte[] doInBackground(URL... params) {
byte[] data;
    Bitmap bi = downloadImage(getPhotoUrl());
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, baos);
    data = baos.toByteArray();
return data;
}
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(byte[] result) {
    postToFacebook(result);
}
```

But the error continues.

How can I fix this?
Thank you!

Comment: either `response` or `response.getGraphObject()` are null/returning null. Have you checked which one it is?

Comment: @WarrenFaith only the response.getGraphObject() is null. The response contains data. In debug mode, I see an error in the response that says: (#100) picture URL is not properly formatted

Comment: You should then check for errors and handle them before you use the getGraphObject() method

Answer (score 1):

The pages I've gone through show the "picture" parameter is a URL, not data you can upload from your computer.

To upload a photo I am using:

```
Request request = Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(),
                  BitmapFactory.decodeStream(this.getAssets().open("YourFile.png")), 
              new Request.Callback(){ 
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                FacebookRequestError error = response.getError();
                if(error != null){
                    Log.i(this.getClass().getName(),"Error publishing.");
                }else{
                    JSONObject graphResponse = response.getGraphObject().getInnerJSONObject();
                    String postId = null;
                    try {
                        postId = graphResponse.getString("id");
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        Log.i("Facebook error", "JSON error " + e.getMessage());
                    }

                    //Logged in Succesfully!        
                }
            }
});
Bundle params = request.getParameters();
params.putString("name", "The title for the photo.");
request.setParameters(params);

request.executeAsync();
```

I am passing a png I have in my assets folder, but you can adapt that part to what you need. Looking at your code it should be straight forward.